# attempting to poll a server however rxjs methods may be incorrect as algorithm breaks

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, polling

so I am attempting to poll my server. I am trying to poll my server every 5 seconds. And the poll times out after one minute. I have a few console logs in the method for debugging but the only console.log that fires even after waiting 5 seconds is `'validate stream start'`

I followed [this](https://blog.angulartraining.com/how-to-do-polling-with-rxjs-and-angular-50d635574965) tutorial without creating a separate service as I just need it for this one page in my application.

I'm willing to bet its a simple error or a misunderstanding in how these rxjs operators work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
startastream(){
    this.startastreamboolan = true;
    let count = 12;
    this.http.get(environment.shochat_content_creator_set_valid_stream_start)
      .subscribe((req: any)=>{
        console.log('validate stream start');
        timer(5000).pipe(
          switchMap(() =>{
            console.log('timer start');
            if(count > 0){
              return this.http.get(environment.check_if_stream_is_active_on_mux)
                .subscribe(
                  (req: any)=>{
                    this.streamready = true;
                    return 0;
                  },
                  error => {
                    count = count -1;
                    console.log(count);

                  });
            }
          }));
      });
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `switchMap` operator on the first `get` request. This is a bad practice to use several nested `subscribe` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### timer

*Creates an Observable that starts emitting after an `dueTime` and emits ever increasing numbers after each `period` of time thereafter.*

```
timer(dueTime: number | Date = 0, periodOrScheduler?: number | SchedulerLike, scheduler?: SchedulerLike): Observable<number>
```

> Its like `interval`, but you can specify when should the emissions start.

In your code, you are forgetting the second parameter of the `timer` operator, which means it will just wait for `5s` and then emit only once. In addition, you are not subscribing to the `timer`, that's why it's not going any further. If you want to poll your server every `5s`, you need to use :

```
timer(0, 5000)
```

Here, the timer won't wait and will directly start emitting values every `5s`.

---

Next, I see that you're using a `switchMap` to create an inner stream, that's great. But If your server takes more than `5s` to process your request, you might want to use `mergeMap` instead as it doesn't cancel the previous ongoing inner streams, it's up to you.

The error here is that the `switchMap` (or the `mergeMap`) takes a callback function which **must** return an `Observable`, the operator will then subscribe to it by itself. Here, you are returning a `Subscription` instead.

Here is what you could do :

```ts
const start$ = this.http.get(startUrl).pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('Stream start'))
);
const poll$ = this.http.get(pollUrl).pipe(
  tap(() => (this.streamReady = true)),
  catchError(error => {
    console.log(error);
    return EMPTY;
  })
);

start$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => timer(0, 5000).pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('Polling every 5s')),
    mergeMap(() => poll$)
  ))
).subscribe();
```

I've created two `Observables` here. `start$`, which is responsible for starting the stream, and `poll$`, which is responsible for polling your server. The idea here is to start the stream, then switch to the `timer` inner stream which will emit every `5s`, and then switch again to another inner stream that will poll the server.

I didn't include the `count` in my example, so the stream will run forever with this code. You should take a look at the `takeUntil` operator for that purpose.

Hope it helped, feel free to ask questions !

Comment: Beautifully done. Thank you for your very detailed answer. This took time, and I appreciate you taking it!!