# where would you put takeUntil RXJS in this code that polls a server?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, polling, takeuntil

So the code below has been developed off the answer I got in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66535569/attempting-to-poll-a-server-however-rxjs-methods-may-be-incorrect-as-algorithm-b) stack overflow question.

the code is designed to poll my server until either a condition on the server is true, or polling has occurred for a minute.

I understand I can stop the polling after a minute using the `takeUntil` RXJS function. However, I have no idea where in the code I would put it in. As every place I put it in that I thought it would go, the code has errored out.

I am also using this tutorial from the learnrxjs website https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil

You'll notice the first line of the `startastream()` function is

`const endtimer = timer(60000);`

This is the condition that would fill the `takeUntil()` argument. So `takeUntil(endtimer)`

```
    start$ = this.http.get(environment.shochat_content_creator_set_valid_stream_start).pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('Stream start'))
  );
  poll$ = this.http.get(environment.check_if_stream_is_active_on_mux).pipe(
    tap(() => (this.streamready = true)),
    catchError(error => {
      console.log(error);
      return EMPTY;
    })
  );

  startastream(){
    const endtimer = timer(60000);
    this.streampollsubscription = this.start$.pipe(
      switchMap(() => timer(0, 5000).pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('Polling every 5s')),
        mergeMap(() => this.poll$)
      ))
    ).subscribe();

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply place it in the pipe after switchMap:

```
    this.streampollsubscription = this.start$.pipe(
      switchMap(() => timer(0, 5000).pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('Polling every 5s')),
        mergeMap(() => this.poll$)
      )),
      takeUntil(endtimer)
    ).subscribe();
```

Check out this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66538473?file=src/app/app.component.ts).